# java DocumentBuilder with DTD validation validates invalid XML

Tags: xml, validation, dtd

I was given a simple XML document under DTD validation with the following structure:

**people.xml**

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-15' ?>

<!DOCTYPE people SYSTEM "people.dtd">

<people>
    <person dni="1234345F" >
        <name>pepe</name>
        Description for pepe
        <age>12</age>
        <subject>maths</subject>
        <subject>history</subject>
    </person>
    <person dni="12343sdfF" >
        Description for marcos
        <name>marcos</name>
        <age>12</age>
        <subject>music</subject>
        <subject>Spanish</subject>
    </person>
    <person dni="345634345F" >
        <name>JL</name>
        <age>25</age>
        <subject>science</subject>
        <subject>maths</subject>
        Description for JL
    </person>
</people>
```

As you can see, the location of the description text node for every person is unknown in the moment of valitation. I have written this DTD:

**people.dtd**

```dtd
<!ELEMENT people (person+)>
<!ELEMENT person (name|age|subject+|#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT age (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT subject (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST person dni CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

I have tried almost every combination for this line **(name|age|subject+|#PCDATA)** but I am still unable to have it matching  with the xml document.

Comment: Sorry about the wrong title! I would have edited the title but I cant see any link to do that.

Comment: To edit the title or the question text,,  click "edit" below the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify order when you have mixed content (http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-mixed-content).

You have to declare `person` like this:

```
<!ELEMENT person (#PCDATA|name|age|subject)*>
```

Comment: What would happen if a given ELEMENT person has no subjects? I need to check there are at least one of them, or more.

Comment: @sonirico - I would suggest adding an element for description so you can specify order and occurrence.